# Add gitparameter in jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, variables, jenkins, input, jenkins-pipeline

I need the userInput when executing the pipeline. 
The input will be the git branch of a particular repository.
As we can configure gitparameter in the jenkins job how do we configure it in the jenkins pipeline.
I have got the pipeline code as follows
>

```
   stage 'promotion'
   def userInput = input(
   id: 'userInput', message: 'Let\'s promote?', parameters: [
   [$class: 'GitParameterDefinition', description: 'Environment', name: 'env',type: 'Branch'],
   [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'uat1', description: 'Target', name: 'target']
])
  echo ("Env: "+userInput['env'])
  echo ("Target: "+userInput['target'])
```

All I get is an empty input box how do I configure it with the git repository in the pipeline itself.

Comment: are you trying to clone some repository based on branch name obtained from user input?

Comment: @PrasadMarne yes correct

Comment: GitParameterDefinition is not available as input type. So i have posted another way of achieving what you want to do. Hope it helps you.

Comment: According to https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/ `gitParameter` is available however there it says "this parameter will present at build-time a choice to select a Git tag (or revision number) which set a parameter for parametrized build." and so far I could not get it working as part of the `input()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow:

```
node { 
stage ('input') { 

   def userInput = input message: 'enter git details',
     parameters: [
     string(defaultValue: 'dev', description: 'branch name', name: 'branch'),
     string(defaultValue: '', description: 'repo url', name: 'url')
     ]

    git branch: userInput['branch'], credentialsId: 'creds', url: userInput['url']
   }
}
```

Comment: this would ask for the branch as string input, I want the branches to be retrieved automatially from git.
I have actually got it by adding active choices plugin and added the steps here: https://apassionatechie.wordpress.com/2017/12/06/jenkins-pipeline-git-branch-as-parameter/

Comment: I think your question was "The input will be the git branch of a particular repository"

Comment: yes the repository will be added in the pipeline but the branches should be retrieved dynamically

Answer (score 0):

There is a [List Git Branches Parameters Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/List+Git+Branches+Parameter+Plugin) which should work:

> This plugin adds ability to choose branches, tags or revisions from git repository configured as a parameter in your builds. Unlike Git Parameter Plugin, this plugin requires a git repository defined instead of reading GIT SCM configuration from your projects

I solved it slightly different by use of `git command` and `ChoiceParameter` which does not require an additional plugin. However it's a bit of a hack, but it works:

```
gitUrl = "https://whateverIsyourscmurl"

//checkout in order to be able to execute git commands
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/master']],
    credentialsId: 'bitbucket.service.user',
    userRemoteConfigs: [
        [url: gitUrl,
            noTags: false]
    ]
])

def selectedTag = "1.0.0"
//get all git tags sorted
command = "git tag  --sort=-v:refname"
gitlog = sh(returnStdout: true, script: command).trim() //or bat() in windows
def gitTags = gitlog.tokenize("\n");

//as there is no default value for "ChoiceParameter" we jus put the found element on top
gitTags = gitTags.minus([selectedTag]); 
gitTags.remove(0) // gitlog also shows the command itself so remove the first element
gitTags.add(0, selectedTag)


ChoiceParameterDefinition currentTag = 
    new ChoiceParameterDefinition(
        'currentTag', 
        gitTags as String[],
        "Git tag")

returnValue = input message: 'Create workorder for ' + currentStage + ' ?', 
        parameters: [currentTag],
        submitterParameter: 'approver'
        description: "whatever"
```